# Solve the following wave initial value problem by using the D'Alembert's formula

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Solve the following wave initial value problem by using the D'Alembert's formula:

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}−4\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}= 0 \text{ with } u(0, x) = 1, \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(0, x) = \cos(x)$$

We also need to plot three snapshots of the solution.

This is my solution using D'Alembert: $u(t,x) = 1 + \frac14[\sin(x+2t) - \sin (x-2t)]$.

I am confused on how I should plot $u(t,x)$. All values of $t$ which I pick as a snapshot look the same. I am not really sure what my professor means by "snapshot". Any ideas?

Comment: That's a standing wave. The "snapshots" should have different vertical scales, but they're otherwise the same. A trig identity gives $$u(t,x) = 1+\frac12\sin(2t)\cos(x)$$ This is an ordinary sinusoid with time-varying amplitude.